# PHP ISO 8601 format conversion issue

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

I want to convert this string '2016-05-30 15:35:00' into **ISO 8601** format which should look like this:

> Expected result : **2016-05-30T15:35:00+05:30**

I tried following, but in the output it's 2 hours less,

```
$phpdate = strtotime('2016-05-30 15:35:00');

echo gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+05:30', $phpdate);
```

> Output : **2016-05-30T13:35:00+05:30**

Have I made a mistake somewhere? or is there an easier way for this conversion?

Comment: use date instead gmdate

Comment: `gmdate` is for UTC instead you need to use `date` like as `date('Y-m-d H:i:sP',$phpdate);`

Comment: thanks for the quick replies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) function of PHP which converts date into `UTC` format instead you need to use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function like as

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");//Set your timezone to Asia/Kolkata

$phpdate = strtotime('2016-05-30 15:35:00');

echo date('c', $phpdate);// 2016-05-30T13:35:00+05:30 if your timezone is of Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: This seems clear but it adds +02:00 to my timezone, how do I specifically add Asia/Kolkata timezone?

Answer (score 1):

for an easier way to handle dates i recommend [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

for your problem it would be :

```
$date = new Carbon("2016-05-30 15:35:00");
echo $date->toIso8601String();
```